# Android: debug app on device with Eclipse and password-protected keystore?

Tags: android, default, signing, keystore

I uploaded my application to Market and then downloaded it to my phone. Now I'm unable to use debug keystore which is used by default by Eclipse ADT Plugin (*Re-installation failed due to different application signatures*) and when I'm trying to setup own keystore in Eclipse->Windows->Android->Build->CustomDebugKeystore, I'm unable to enter password or accept keystore and type password later.

Is there anything I can do or only way do debug app on device is to uninstall market version and deal with default debug keystore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to delete the market version before you can reinstall the debug version onto the device. Android keeps track of applications based on their package names so you can't have more than one installed w/ the same name at the same time. If you really wanted to keep both the market version and the version you're working on installed you'd have to change the package name of the new one, then change it back when you want to update it to the market.

Comment: or: compile release version and install it on device with ADB

Comment: additional info - **adb install -r <file>** forces reinstall of existing application, which can be used as simulation of upgrading app as in Android Market

Comment: Can't believe we can't set our own keystore for debugging. I guess we'll have to export to APK first every time after publishing to market :(

Answer (score 0):

Just realised this:

What if you made a copy of your keystore file, changed the password as in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889238/java-keystore-change-passwords) to the default Android password 'android', then used that in Eclipse?

Comment: It is not enough, there are passwords for keystore and specific key, also key must be named "androiddebugkey". So there is no way to do it easily in Eclipse without modyfying ADT plugin.