# Keystore change passwords

Tags: java, keystore

I currently have a keystore, with a particular password that only I should know. I now need to give access to that keystore to someone else, so I would like to either:

1) Change the password, so I can share it with others and let them sign
2) Create a different password and allow them to sign with it.

Is this possible? and - if yes - how?

Answer (score 570, accepted):

Keystore only has one password. You can change it using keytool:

```
keytool -storepasswd -keystore my.keystore
```

To change the key's password:

```
keytool -keypasswd  -alias <key_name> -keystore my.keystore
```

Comment: Great, so the signature of the apk will be the same? Just the password will change? This is what I need too. Chose a bad password, now need to change it.

Comment: Signature won't change, as app is NOT signed with the keystore, but with certificate you keep in keystore.

Comment: keyName is the name of the alias, eg. -alias Dipu

Comment: To remove the password for key, one has to set the same password as for keystore, may be useful for someone ;-)

Comment: Does this apply to `.jks` too? My keystore is .jks generated by Android Studio

Comment: @CodigosTutoriales `.jks` stands for **J**ava **K**ey**S**tore, it's the same thing.

Comment: Found this tool which has a more visual view of of the jks files http://keystore-explorer.org/index.html

Comment: And how can we do it programmatically?

Comment: The default password is `changeit`.

Comment: When I try this with a `.bks` keystore, I get `java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format`.

Answer (score 97):

> [How can I] Change the password, so I can share it with others and let them sign

Using keytool:

```bash
keytool -storepasswd -keystore /path/to/keystore
Enter keystore password:  changeit
New keystore password:  new-password
Re-enter new keystore password:  new-password
```

Comment: does this change the password for the key inside too?

Comment: No. Keystore is one things, passwords (note plural) is another. Use `keytool -keypasswd -alias <KeyName> -keystore my.keystore` to change password of private key `<KeyName>`

Comment: after enter keystore pass -changeit it gives error keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Comment: @Dipu, I am getting same error. Have you managed to resolved that

Comment: You can verify that the password has changed (if you have doubt) by running the exact same command again. After it prompts for the existing password, if you enter a password that is incorrect, it'll say you entered the wrong password or the file has been tampered with and abort.

Comment: The same for me. "changeit" doesn't work. I assume Android Studio with Gradle generated my keystore for the first time at the moment of the first app build. Does anybody know how to see or to reset the password that was generated by Android studio?

Answer (score 54):

**Changing keystore password**

```
$ keytool -storepasswd -keystore keystorename
Enter keystore password:  <old password>
New keystore password: <new password>
Re-enter new keystore password: <new password>
```

**Changing keystore alias password**

```
$ keytool -keypasswd -keystore keystorename -alias aliasname
Enter keystore password:  
New key password for <aliasname>: 
Re-enter new key password for <aliasname>:
```

Note:

- `keystorenam`: name of your keystore (with path if you are in different folder)
- `aliasname`: alias name you used when creating (if name has space you can use `\)`

For example:

```
$ keytool -keypasswd -keystore keystorename -alias stop\ watch
```

Comment: It works thank you! One more thing I want to add to change alias name which I wanted and got from a forum. keytool -changealias -keystore my.keystore -alias my_name -destalias my_new_name

Comment: While changing the alias password I get: UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key

Any suggestions?

Comment: @Foo did you ever figure out that issue? I'm getting the same error

Comment: Changing keystore alias password  what ever you shown doesn't work, It won't ask New key password for <aliasname>. It asks existing password for <aliasname> which is not known in this case.

Comment: I still get Cannot recover key at the step: New key password for <aliasname>:  

Any ideas? I just created the key in Android Studio, uploaded, realized I had to update something and now it doesnt work :/

Answer (score 23):

To change the password for a key `myalias` inside of the keystore `mykeyfile`:

```
keytool -keystore mykeyfile -keypasswd -alias myalias
```

Comment: What is "inside key"?

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation. You can change the password of the keystore or the password of one of the keys you have stored on the keystore. That's what I mean with "inside key".

Answer (score 11):

For a full programmatic change (e.g. install program) and no prompting

```
#!/bin/bash -eu

NEWPASSWORD=${1}
OLDPASSWORD=${2}

keytool -storepasswd -new "${NEWPASSWORD}" \
  -storepass "${OLDPASSWORD}" \
  -keystore /path/to/keystore
```

Full disclosure:  I DO NOT recommend running this command line in a shell, as the old and new passwords will be saved in the shell's history, and visible in console.

Answer (score 10):

[KeyStore Explorer](http://keystore-explorer.org/) is an open source GUI replacement for the Java command-line utilities keytool and jarsigner. KeyStore Explorer presents their functionality, and more, via an intuitive graphical user interface.

1. Open an existing KeyStore
2. Tools -> Set KeyStore password

Comment: best solution! Better than writing to the terminal. Using this software - I was able to change the passwords and add new key pairs. Highly recommend

Comment: Fantastic little app, worked like a charm!

Answer (score 8):

If the keystore contains other key-entries with different password you have to change them also or you can isolate your key to different keystore using below command,

```
keytool -importkeystore  -srckeystore mystore.jck -destkeystore myotherstore.jks -srcstoretype jceks
-deststoretype jks -srcstorepass mystorepass -deststorepass myotherstorepass -srcalias myserverkey
-destalias myotherserverkey -srckeypass mykeypass -destkeypass myotherkeypass
```

Answer (score 6):

There are so many answers here, but if you're trying to change the jks password on a Mac in Android Studio.  Here are the easiest steps I could find

1) Open Terminal and cd to where your .jks is located

2) **keytool -storepasswd -new NEWPASSWORD -keystore YOURKEYSTORE.jks**

3) enter your current password