# Tried many answers to get my keytool.exe to open but failed

Tags: java, android, eclipse, path, keytool

I was trying to get keytool.exe running but the command prompt disappear so fast as soon as i open it.

I also tried to manually type in the command prompt

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin

it says 'program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. I was unable to open program file folder itself.

I went to environment variables and change the path to

1)C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin
2)C:\Program Files\
and more diff related path, etc etc but the result in command prompt is still giving me that error.

when i type in 'C:>java' it showed the list
(I attached the screen shot picture of the cmd but new users not allowed)

i followed this direction from this link

[I can’t find the Android keytool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997348/cant-find-the-android-keytool)

and none of them were able to solve my problem. Am I missing anything else? I hope to solve this problem soon.

!!!UPDATED!!!

I found out that I have to type in cd before the path

"cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin"

I assumed that if i type in C: and press enter it would change directory to C: and after I can type the path from there but always getting error even at "Program Files" itself.

Thanks everyone!

> here was the example in my command
>   prompt
>
> > C:>Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin
> >
> > 'Program' is not recognized as an
> >     internal or external command, operable
> >     program or batch file.

added the 'cd' before the path and...

> > C:>cd C:\Program
> >     Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin
> >
> > C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin>

Comment: Did you type `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin\keytool.exe"` ?

Comment: keytool is not a clickable program - it is to be interacted with from a command prompt.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of opening keytool.exe right away, open cmd, then `cd` your way to keytool.exe's directory. From there run `keytool.exe [parameters]`. The prompt will stay open and you can see what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

From the command line try quoting the command (because of the space in `Program Files`):

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin\keytool.exe"
```