# Keytool opens than closes super fast

Tags: android, keytool

All- When I tried to open keytool (by double-clicking it in my bin file of my JDK), the window pops up but than closes really fast. I looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983946/tried-many-answers-to-get-my-keytool-exe-to-open-but-failed) and tried to run it from the command line but was met with this
[image] 
Did I type in everything OK or is there something else I can try?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're supposed to do a `cd` to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin`, and type in `keytool.exe` to run the program

Or simply remove the `cd` and it will work fine

Comment: I am a little confused. So like cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin (return) keytool.exe?

Comment: Yes. `cd` changes directory. First you change to the directory containing the tool, then run it.

Comment: @androdcurious Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that if you are not comfortable with the command line tools in Java, it might be good to have an Eclipse plugin that does the work behind the scenes.

Here is one Eclipse plugin for keytool operations that has worked well for me: http://keytool.sourceforge.net/