# Obtaining Google API's key in Windows 7

Tags: android, google-maps

So I want to get a key to use `Google API` in Eclipse with Android.
I have followed the instruction [here](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html) and [here](http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=6&number=130) but I have the following issue,  after I type like this :

```
C:\Users\User>$ keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\User\
.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

the `cmd` said like this :

`'$' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

So I tried to delete the `$` and the `cmd` said :

`'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Can I get some help with this issue?

Comment: Your typing in a Linux shell command. It's probably keytool.exe, and there shouldn't be a '$'. The '$' just indicates that it's a shell command.

Comment: Thanks Sir :D
Yes, i also tried to delete the "$" and the cmd said "keytool" is not exist :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the keytool executable (see [I can’t find the Android keytool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997348/cant-find-the-android-keytool)) and type in:

```
keytool.exe -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\User\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to exceute the execute from the directory where keytool is located or add the directory to the path. A google search should help you finding out how to work with cmd.

Comment: Thanks :D
Can you help more?i have done some research's but almost all doc's or question's answer is the one that i post....