# Access denied when obtaining android md5 fingerprint

Tags: android, cmd, key, google-maps-android-api-2

When obtaining my md5 fingerprint for an Android app I have encountered problems when entering the keystore command on both the cmd and jdk bin prompt:

```
keystore is an invalid command
```

In the cmd I got this error,which I researched and found that it means my keystore path is incorrect.So I double checked my path and it was correct and found a tutorial explaining to enter the same command through the jdk bin cmd prompt:

```
Access denied
```

key store address is:

```
C:\Users\Brian\.android\debug.keystore
```

The command I'm using is as follows:

```
keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\Brian\.android\debug.keystore   -storepass android -keypass android
```

Comment: Do you have a keystore at the given path?

Comment: which commands are you executing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to obtain.
Maby this answer can help
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14042038/928591

I see what your problem is, you are trying to obtain a **debug key** but you specify a path.
but try to just copy paste this commnad without modifying it.

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

it worked for me to obtain my debug key for a facebook app.
I could be wrong about this but I think this should work

**Edit**
Did some digging, the keytool comes with the java jdk. like commonsware answerd [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997348/cant-find-the-android-keytool)
so do you have the JDK or the SDK installed is my next question.

**Edit (another)**
to answer you question in the comment take a look here.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

**finale update**
this is the last update for this particular answer.
Browse to the JDK folder and execute the command from that directory.

kind regards

Comment: I'm trying to obtain the md5 fingerprint for using the google maps api.

Comment: So the link I provided was not of any use Iam afraid?

Comment: I tried the command but still saying 'keytool' is not recognised.

Comment: I think your path variable is not set correctly to use this command just anywhere except for the folder where the keytool program is located

Comment: How do I set this up as I went to user account variables and there was no jdk variable.Is there a different way to change the path?

Comment: Yes I just checked it is installed but I have reinstalled just to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I just checked online on oracle and it states that the jdk path is not PATH variable is not set by default and is optional.So my question is how do you set up the jdk variable?

Comment: I added the path but it still says that keytool is not recognised.Any ideas?

Comment: yhe browse to the folder where you jdk is installed would something be like your/install/location/jdk<version>/contents/home/bin open a terminal/cmd promt on this location and execute your command there. as you can see if you browse to this folder is that the key tool is located there. so that should work

Comment: I am on osx user so I am not sure if the paths reference are the same.

Comment: yeah I opened a cmd in the jdk folder and success :)