# Android - in which directory is the keytool tool

Tags: android, keytool

I am trying to do this command:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

But I am not sure which directory this is in. I thought it would be here

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>
```

But it isn't. Would anyone know from where this command is meant to be made?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to get your MD5 fingerprint : 
change directory to :   C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\JDK folder\bin 
and then execute 
keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android

Comment: thank you. I got this error: keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: C:\Users\.android\debug.keystore ..would you know why? :)

Comment: first find your debug.keystore : start-> search for "debug.keystore" and put that path in place of C:Users\.android\debug.keystore

Answer (score 3):

keytool comes with the Java SDK. You should find it in the directory that contains javac, etc

from:
[I can’t find the Android keytool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997348/cant-find-the-android-keytool)

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_14\bin

Answer (score 1):

Run this patah or paste it in address bar and you will get you keystore file :

```
%HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore
```

and if you want to open .keystore file's folder then use :

```
 %HOMEPATH%\.android\
```

For windows only.

Answer (score 0):

you can find this way 
C:\Users.android\debug.keystore

keytool -list -v -keystore c:\users\your_user_name.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android