# i get "bash: keytool: command not found." when Obtaining Google Map Key on linux fedora

Tags: android, linux, google-maps, fedora

i would like to use Google maps in my android application, and i knew that firstly  i have to Obtain  Google Map Key

I'm using Linux fedora OS and i typed this in my terminal

```
[dinareda@localhost ~]$ keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

But I get:

> > bash: key tool: command not found...

Any help please?

Comment: It means that `keytool` is not installed in your system.

Comment: how can i install it ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2998451/1983854

Comment: Thanks a lot, but he is windows and I'm Linux fedora
thanks again for your time

Comment: Oh, I see. `apt-get install <packet>` usually works.

Comment: ok,thanks i fix it in another way 
thanks,i appreciate you help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`keytool` is part of JRE, search for it in JRE/JDK directory or simply `locate keytool`

Comment: i did that and this what i get
>>/home/dinareda/glassfish-3.1.2.2/mq/bin/imqkeytool
>>/home/dinareda/glassfish-3.1.2.2/mq/bin/imqkeytool.exe
>>/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_21/bin/keytool
>>/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_21/jre/bin/keytool
>>/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_21/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/keytool.1
>>/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_21/man/man1/keytool.1

Comment: Use this `/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_21/bin/keytool`

Comment: sorry but i get a list of  Key and Certificate Management Tool


Use "keytool -command_name -help" for usage of command_name