# How to find "Keytool" for android app

Tags: android, firebase

I'm currently trying the new feature of firebase, and it asks me to provide 'Debug signing certificate SHA-1', I've read the document of how to get the code but I don't know where to find "keytool". By the way, what is the function of this code, will it make differences if I don't provide one in firebase?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In windows:

- Navigate to you **JRE** folder in Windows File Explorer - to the directory
  with the **keytool.exe** in the **JDK -> bin folder**. Mine is in `C:\Program
  Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin` but try browsing to the Java folder and
  see what version you have and change the path accordingly.
- Right click on the mouse while pressing shift key on your keyboard.
- Click on **Open command window here**.
- To get the debug certificate fingerprint enter in the command window this:

  ```
  keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore  %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
  ```
- The keytool utility prompts you to enter a password for the keystore. The default password for the debug keystore is **android** (or no password, just hit enter). The keytool then prints the fingerprint to the terminal. For example:

  ```
  Certificate fingerprint: SHA1: DA:39:A3:EE:5E:6B:4B:0D:32:55:BF:EF:95:60:18:90:AF:D8:07:09
  ```

Comment: Add ./keytool for powershell

Answer (score 9):

Another place is inside of Android Studio, incase you have already have install it:

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\keytool.exe
```

Comment: If you are creating a signing key then you need to use this Android version of keytool. 

The Android sdk requires a key where the keystore and the key have passwords. The java version only creates keystores with a password on the store not the key.

Answer (score 1):

From [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997348/i-can-t-find-the-android-keytool)

> keytool comes with the Java SDK. You should find it in the directory that contains javac, etc.

Answer (score 1):

(For Windows)

ERRORS I was getting:

- `keytool : The term 'keytool' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`
- `keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore` `java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore`

SOLUTION:

Repeat the first steps that [@amitai-fensterheim answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37578485/9192954) to the current question.
Steps:

> 1. Navigate to you JRE folder in Windows File Explorer - to the directory with the keytool.exe in the JDK -> bin folder. Mine is in C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin but try browsing to the Java folder and see what version you have and change the path accordingly.
> 2. Right click on the mouse while pressing shift key on your keyboard.
> 3. Click on Open command window here.

Then write this on your terminal:

```
.\keytool.exe -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore $env:USERPROFILE\.android\debug.keystore
```

Finally, press `ENTER` to get the SHA1 certificate.

Answer (score -1):

Follow these simple steps :

1. Check the **JRE-> bin** folder or bin folder where **keytool.exe** is present. copy the folder path and change directory of terminal with these path.
2. `keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore  %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore`

Type above command and take your sha-256 or sha-1 fingerprints.