# How to add the debug signing certificate and get (SHA-1) from command propmt

Tags: android, firebase, cmd

when i open command prompt it look like this

[image]

so when i write the command of getting the SHA-1 that what happend

[image]

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727912/sha-1-fingerprint-of-keystore-certificate

Comment: this one help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/33479550/3406577

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997348/i-can-t-find-the-android-keytool

Comment: The keytool executable is in the Java SDK bin directory. It appears that the Java SDK bin directory is not in your PATH variable. Also, the line continuation character for the cmd.exe shell is a CARET '^' and not a REVERSE SOLIDUS '\'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go for Debug Mode:

> keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android

**EDIT try this:**

Getting your SHA1 key is a little more complicated on a Windows system so, follow along with my steps here:

1) Open Command Prompt by pressing Start+R and typing cmd.exe.

2) Using Windows Explorer, find where your JDK directory is located (Usually Program Files >> Java) and copy the path.

3) In Command Prompt, type cd followed by the directory of your JDK’s bin directory. e.g: cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin is the command I use (Yours may vary).

4) Using Windows Explorer, find where your .android directory is located (Usually under Users >> [YOUR WINDOWS USERNAME]) and copy the path.

5) Now, use this command below:

> keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore
>   [PATH_TO_.ANDROID_DIRECTORY] -list -v

Replacing [PATH_TO_.ANDROID_DIRECTORY] with the path you copied. Note that you should be running this command in terminal/command prompt in your JDK’s bin directory (You did this in Step 3).

You should then be prompted with the password as normal which you can enter (The password is android) . After that, you’ll see the list of certificates printed to the screen. You want the SHA1 key.

In Command Prompt, it’s a little more tricky to copy the result so, to do that, follow these instructions:

1) Right-click on the Command Prompt.

2) Select Mark.

3) Highlight the SHA1 key.

4) Right-click again and the text will then be copied to your clipboard. You can now enter this on the Google Developer’s Console.

Comment: it said alias is not recognized

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Android Studio
2. Open Your Project
3. Click on Gradle (From Right Side Panel, you will see Gradle Bar)
4. Click on Refresh (Click on Refresh from Gradle Bar, you will see List Gradle scripts of your Project)
5. Click on Your Project (Your Project Name form List (root))
6. Click on Tasks
7. Click on android
8. Double Click on signingReport (You will get SHA1 and MD5 in Run Bar)

Comment: User needs to add debug signing certificate using cmd, not Android Studio.