# Strange result when changing Android keystore password

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

My original password for Android keystore is `123`, when I changed to `abc` using the command

```
keytool -storepasswd -keystore my.keystore
```

Now when I export the app using Eclipse, I found that the 1st password to be entered is `abc`, but the 2nd password to be entered is still `123`

Is this the normal result?

So how can I change both password?

Thanks.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889238/keystore-change-passwords

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second password protects the private key in the key-store. You should be able to change it using the command

```
keytool -keypasswd -alias <myKeyAlias> -keystore my.keystore
```

Replace  with the name of the key displayed in Eclipse.

Comment: If the 2nd password protects the private key in the key-store, so what does the 1st password do?

Comment: The password is for the overall keystore. Without it you are not able to read anything event the certificates that do not have a private key.

Comment: I accepted as correct answer. Just some followup if you don't mind: 1. is it common to use the same password? 2. What are the risk if my keystore and password are leaked?