# Android - Eclipse: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Tags: android, code-signing, keystore

I'm developing an android project signing my app (while developing) with the debug.keystore ... Now I need to use the "real" production keystore (the one which I use when I upload my apk to the play store), while developing to test some in app purchases things.

So it would be great to use the production keystore in eclipse to start the app on my device, so I could use the eclipse debugger etc.

After finishing this testing I want to switch back to the debug.keystore .

So I tried to replace the debug.keystore file in the .android folder, but then I get the error:

> Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

since I have not entered the password yet. Where do I enter the password in eclipse (juno)?

Or is there better way (in a wizzard for example) in eclipse, without replacing the debug.keystore file directly, to specify the current keystore that should be used when launching my android application from eclipse run button?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754060/how-to-set-a-custom-keystore-for-debugging-in-eclipse-for-android

Answer (score 6):

**Change the password to default password i.e. `android`.**

[here is the SO link . how to Change the Keystore password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889238/keystore-change-passwords)

Comment: hi, sry, but i cant do that, because my app is already in the store (im developing an update) with the signed production key

Comment: Default password ll be android. Try once. Might your prblm get solved

Comment: But changing the password will change the keystore, doesnt it? And the keystore would not be recorgnized as the same as Im already in the play store ...

Comment: if you have not changed previously. Then there ll be no problem I think.

Comment: Changing the password of the keystore itself should not change the signature key within the keystore so you should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to just enter the password in eclipse for the release keystore (like in the export dialog).

Since there is no dialog & I don't want to mess with eclipse internal configuration I use a custom keystore as a work-around.

Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21332511/993494) for how to use your release keystore for debugging

Answer (score 0):

If you have taken the backup of the debug.keystore and replaced it then it should not be a issue in replacing it back, However you can specify the debug.keystore from

Eclipse tool bar > Windows> Preference> Android> Build> Custom Keystore.

Also if you want the Keystore to be recreated simply delete it, eclipse will recreated on next run.

Comment: Thank you, that looks good: Now i can specify the path to the keystore, however i can't set the corresponding password. I can't see a password input field ...

Comment: it only allows debug keystore, i.e default password is "android". For production builds you need to use Export Android Application

Answer (score 0):

If you specify a custom keystore, you have to make sure that the entries are what the eclipse environment expects. Maybe they're not lining up with those requirements? [Check out the docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

specifically the Signing in Debug Mode section for details