# How to set a custom keystore for debugging in eclipse for android

Tags: java, android, apk, code-signing, android-keystore

I have a custom keystore that I use for signing my apk. now I want to use the same keystore for debugging. when I go to eclipse->windows->preferences->android->build and set my custom key store I get "Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect"?

Comment: Eclipse creates a debug key when you run your app through it

Comment: check out this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9019833/how-can-i-specify-location-of-debug-keystore-for-android-ant-debug-builds

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I had the same issue and here are the steps to properly create a custom keystore that can be used for debugging in Eclipse:

Basically what you should do is that change both `storepasswd` and `keypasswd` for the alias `androiddebugkey` to "android".

Here are the commands:

```
keytool -changealias -keystore mykeystore.keystore -alias [old alias] -destalias androiddebugkey
keytool -keypasswd -keystore mykeystore.keystore -alias androiddebugkey
keytool -storepasswd -keystore mykeystore.keystore
```

If you don't know your old alias, look it up using

```
keytool -list -v -keystore mykeystore.keystore
```

in Command prompt not able to enter the password

Comment: This is a great way to switch from the default debug keystore to your release/custom one and still be able to debug! Great answer Saeid!

Comment: worth noting: if "App Signing Certificate" is enabled, then this is not going to work.

Comment: For android studio users, follow steps here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965058/where-is-debug-keystore-in-android-studio/39330177

Answer (score 9):

Simplest way to set custom keystor.

No need of commands.

Steps (for ADT):

1.Export any project (It will show you an option to create custom keystore).

[image]

create your keystore with an extention  "**.keystore**" and give password android and press next.

2.[image]

give alias name = **androiddebugkey** and password = **android**

now press finish and your keystore is ready.

1.Go to windows -> preference

and give the path of your custom keystore file

[image]

Comment: Just make sure to clean the project before launching. Sometimes the eclipse will cache the previous key and ignore the new setting.

Answer (score 5):

I got the same problem when trying to debug the released apk.. so I tried the Saeid solution with no success. Then I found this blog (http://blogprogramistyandroid.blogspot.com.br/2011/04/converting-release-keys-to-debug.html) which I got the simplest solution for the problem:

Make this command:

keytool -importkeystore -v -srckeystore release.keystore -destkeystore custom-debug.keystore -srcstorepass release-pass -deststorepass android -srcalias release-key -destalias androiddebugkey -srckeypass release-pass -destkeypass android

Of course substitute passwords and alias of source keystore with the one used in creation of release keystore.

Done

Comment: And of course, don't forget to do a rebuild after putting your new custom-debug.keystore in c:\users\xxx\.andrdoid\debug.keystore

Answer (score 1):

We have the same problem some time ago at our office. Since we needed this quite often we wrote a simple script to make it easy to to convert release keystores to debug ones.

The script is available on https://github.com/IntellexApps/key2debug

We are using it for some time now, so should be quite stable.

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

After change the keystore content, you can setup eclipse in: `Preferences->Android->Build`, as show below:
[Eclipse change debug keystore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbFgb.png)