# jarsigning using a keystore whose password includes a space

Tags: java, android, jarsigner

I'm signing an APK using a keystore whose password includes spaces, using `jarsigner`. I'm specifying `-storepass` and then putting the password in quotes, e.g. `-storepass "my password 123"`.

The sign always goes wrong though, because the key hash is not what I expect it to be. This is crucial for automating the build of my Android app without any user input.

Comment: So use a passphrase without spaces.

Comment: Read the answer I put ;)

Answer (score 4):

`jarsigner` seems to have an issue with passwords that contain spaces. When entering them after being prompted, it is fine, but using the parameter does not work. So, rather than generating a whole new keystore, change the password to something without spaces like so (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889238/keystore-change-passwords))

For the store password:

```
keytool -storepasswd -keystore my.keystore
```

And you probably also want to change the key's password:

```
keytool -keypasswd  -alias <key_name> -keystore my.keystore
```

Comment: Worked for me and yes, passwords with spaces also caused issues for me.